# Bug of ChoiceDialog

Tags: bugs, syntax, input, input-forms

I am using Mathematica 13.1 on Windows 11.

I have the following bug with ChoiceDialog:

```
list = {"EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment", 
   "EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment", 
   "EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment", 
   "EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment", "EXperiment"};
parameter = ChoiceDialog["Value = ", list]
```

[image]

I.e., the list does not match the dialog window. This issue is not present in Mathematica 12.1:

[image]

Could you please tell me how to fix it/what is an alternative to `ChoiceDialog` providing however the same opportunity of choosing the values of the list by clicking on them and delaying the evaluation of the code until the choice is made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

From the documentation, "ChoiceDialog allows the sequence of buttons to linewrap by default if needed, and supports the same [`Appearance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Appearance.html) option settings as [`SetterBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html) to specify other button configurations."

On my system, specifying the `Appearance` appears to resolve this

```
list = ConstantArray["EXperiment", 16];

parameter = 
 ChoiceDialog["Value = ", list, Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

@BobHanlon is right. On windows 11 with MM 13.2.1 you need the vertical setting.
Otherwise it will be incomplete (should be a bug?)

```
Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, Automatic}
```

is fine to!

[image]